# Alert Dialog Button Pressed returning 0 values always

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

So, I want to detect button pressed by the user when an alert dialog pops up. This is my code.

```
public class AlertUtils {

    private int BTN_PRESSED;

    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    public AlertUtils(Context context){
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    }

    public int ShowAlertWithTwoButtons(String Title,String Message,String PositiveButtonText,
                                        String NegativeButtonText){
        builder.setTitle(Title);
        builder.setMessage(Message);

        builder.setPositiveButton(PositiveButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                BTN_PRESSED = i;
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(NegativeButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                BTN_PRESSED = i;
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
        return BTN_PRESSED;
    }
}
```

By calling `ShowAlertWithTwoButtons` method, returns int value detecting Positive or Negative Button pressed. My Problem is it's giving me default 0 value when I chose from an alert dialog and when I again open us alert dialog it returns the correct value.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Read more about [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog)

Comment: @waqaslam, what's wrong? it gives me the Button click int value in second time, forth time,etc. in short in even numer of clicks.

Comment: @AliAhmed, its return type is void.

Comment: your method is returning default value as you are not waiting for click. This you can debug yourself.

Comment: ShowAlertWithTwoButtons will always return 0 immediately, because showing a dialog is asynchronous. You need to rely on dialog's button click listeners.

Comment: @waqaslam, i got your point then why it returns correct value on even number clicks?

Comment: @waqaslam whats the other way that i can return value from click listeners?

Comment: Even numbers? Now where did that come from?

Comment: @waqaslam, yes when alert dialog opens up at first time it returns 0 default value, but on second time it returns correct value of the button pressed, i have even checked logs as well.

Comment: Why this question voted down ?
if he did something wrong or understood something wrong we should correct him without voting the question down

Comment: @BasilBattikhi: You can't argue with the downvoter for the logic behind the downvoting. Just let it go ;)

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I don't mind. and it's okay to criticize. Just let it go man.

Comment: Down voting a question may prevent the question's owner to ask again,!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll always get `BTN_PRESSED` with `0` value whenever you're instantiating your `AlertUtils` object and the calling the `ShowAlertWithTwoButtons` method. But you'll get another value if you're recalling the `ShowAlertWithTwoButtons` again.

I think what you're currently doing is like the following:

```
// First, you're instantiating the object
AlertUtils alertUtils = new AlertUtils(getContext());

// then you're calling the method
int pressedButton = alertUtils.ShowAlertWithTwoButtons("title", "message", "yes", "no");

// which will return pressedButton as 0

// then you calling the method again after clicked yes or no
int anotherPressedButton = alertUtils.ShowAlertWithTwoButtons("title", "message", "yes", "no");

// which will not zero. But can be -1, -2, -3 like in the
// https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html
```

Which is incorrect if want to get the button value directly after the click because of *asynchronous* nature of AlertDialog interface.

Instead, you need to add a listener (ohh no, another listener) to your AlertUtils.

---

**UPDATE**

You need to add another listener for click button, something like this:

```
public class AlertUtils {

    public interface Listener {
      void onButtonClicked(int pressedButton);
    }

    private Listener mListener;

    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    public AlertUtils(Context context, Listener listener){
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void ShowAlertWithTwoButtons(String Title,String Message,String PositiveButtonText,
                                        String NegativeButtonText){
        ...

        builder.setPositiveButton(PositiveButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                mListener.onButtonClicked(i);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(NegativeButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                mListener.onButtonClicked(i);
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
}
```

then you can create and call the method with:

```
// create the listener to listen for the clicked button.
AlertUtils.Listener listener = new AlertUtils.Listener() {
      @Override
      public void onButtonClicked(int pressedButton) {
        // here you'll receive the button value
        // do something here.
      }
   };

AlertUtils alertUtils = new AlertUtils(getContext(), listener);

// then you're calling the method
alertUtils.ShowAlertWithTwoButtons("title", "message", "yes", "no");
```

Comment: You got my point, but i want to return value from onclicklisteners?

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the answer, although there is no need to return value from the function as we already returning values by callback method. if you can just edit that part that will also help others to use this answer as well. Thanks again. appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome ;).
You're correct about the returning value, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try in this way. Make AlertUtils class like this.

```
public class AlertUtils {
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
private AlertDialogListener alertDialogListener;

// Interface to send back the response of click
interface AlertDialogListener {
    void onClick(int a);
}

public AlertUtils(Context context, AlertDialogListener alertDialogListener) {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    this.alertDialogListener = alertDialogListener;
}

public void ShowAlertWithTwoButtons(String Title, String Message, String PositiveButtonText,
                                    String NegativeButtonText) {
    builder.setTitle(Title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.setPositiveButton(PositiveButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // if you want to pass the actual value of i,then pass the i in onClick or if you want 1 on 
            // positive button click then pass 1 here.
            alertDialogListener.onClick(1);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(NegativeButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // if you want to pass the actual value of i, then pass the i in onClick or if you want 1 on 
            // negative button click then pass 0 here.
            alertDialogListener.onClick(0);
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

}

Call the dialog in this way where you need this.

```
  AlertUtils alertUtils = new AlertUtils(getContext(), new AlertUtils.AlertDialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int a) {
            if (a == 1) {
                // Do your work on Positive button click
            } else {
                // Do your work on Negative button click
            }
        }
    });
    alertUtils.ShowAlertWithTwoButtons("Alert Dialog", "Alert Dialog Description ", "Positive", "Negative");
```